# #include <AudioToolbox/AudioFormat.h> not found

Tags: xcode, frameworks

This has been driving me crazy. I've removed the framework and re-added it a million times from the build-phases tab. I keep getting this error from 4 different files from EZAudio (installed via pods). Whats crazy is that till about a few minutes ago everything was building smoothly. Then i tried building for my device and that popped up. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?